# usa + united-states tag merge

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I manually changed the only two instances of [us](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us) into [usa](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa); it should also be merged with [united-sates](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-sates). I'm not sure which one has to be kept.

Comment: Links to tags: http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa (x17) and http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states (x7).

Comment: (Also, the syntax `[tag:usa]` works in Meta posts. I suggest using it for tag requests if possible.)

Comment: I agree with the idea of using "usa" instead of "us", but not in merging "usa" with "united-states". It may be more appropriate to use "usa" as a synonim for "united-states".

Comment: @StevenDrennon: please notice someone _already_ did that (dunno if by hand or script or what), that's why I flagged for adding [tag:status-completed] ;)

Comment: Ahhh! I hadn't checked that. Still not sure that I agree.

Comment: Since I use either interchangably, what would be the most general one that is understandable?  usa or united-states?

Comment: @MichaelF: if we use [tag:usa] then it would make sense to use also all other abbreviations, such as [tag:uk]. But I feel it is better to be verbose and much more clear, so I'd go for [tag:united-states] and [tag:united-kingdom].

Comment: @Lohoris Works for me...means we'll also have to change England or Britain as well, since those two seem to be in use as well.

Comment: @MichaelF: well, technically England is not the same thing, I'd keep that separate. (Great) Britain isn't the same thing either, but I guess it's similar enough to be awarded a merge.

Comment: US and USA merge is done and updated...oh what fun.